# Check in UIImage.init existence of image in bundle

Tags: swift, uikit, uiimage

I want to write init for UIImage, which check if image exists in Assets of .main bundle (application level) - takes it from .main, and if not - takes it from .currentModule (package level)

For now it works like only taking from .currentModule:

```
public extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(originalName: String) {
        self.init(named: originalName, in: .currentModule, with: nil)
    }
}
```

and I want to find way if `self.init(named: originalName, in: .main, with: nil)` returns `nil`, call `self.init(named: originalName, in: .currentModule, with: nil)`
so write something like

```
public extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(originalName: String) {
        if let _ = self.init(named: originalName, in: .main, with: nil) 
    else
        self.init(named: originalName, in: .currentModule, with: nil)
    }
}
```

But it does not compile

This example compiles, but here is double work initialising image in .main bundle:

```
public extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(originalName: String) {
        if originalName == "" {
            return nil
        } else if let _ = UIImage(named: originalName, in: .main, with: nil) {
            self.init(named: originalName, in: .main, with: nil)
        } else {
            self.init(named: originalName, in: .currentModule, with: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

(Just if you wonder for what to use init for this purpose and with 'originalName: String' parameter, - we and our clients already have large codebase which uses such init and there is an enum instead of String)

Comment: How about writing a static factory method instead?

Comment: @Sweeper Don't want to change API. UIImage(originalName:) already uses by library customers, it will be bad experience if they need to rewrite their code.

Comment: I think swift package will only work with `current` module instead of main

Comment: @TejaNandamuri it is public initialiser so will be run from application level.  Last code snippet I've added produce result I want to get.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public extension UIImage {
    convenience init?(originalName: String) {
        if let image = UIImage(named: originalName, in: .main, with: nil) {
            self.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
        } else if let image = UIImage(named: originalName, in: .currentModule, with: nil) {
            self.init(cgImage: image.cgImage!)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this doesn't address OP question

Comment: It does address the OP's question. This solution resolves the issue of initializing the UIImage twice, if the image has been found in main bundle. However, it is now a back- and forth from UIImage to cgImage to UIImage, and that is probably not much of an improvement.

Comment: cgImage returns an optional. It would be much easier to move the cgImage part to the `if let` above and unwrap it as well.  `if let cgImage = UIImage(named: originalName, in: .main, with: nil)?.cgImage  {` `self.init(cgImage: cgImage)`